# Compiling OpenGL shaders causes syntax errors

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have two simple shaders (vertex and fragment)

## Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

//=============================================
//---[Structs/Vertex Data]---------------------
//=============================================

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

//=============================================
//---[Variables]-------------------------------
//=============================================

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

//=============================================
//---[Vertex Shader]---------------------------
//=============================================

void main()
{
   gl_Position = projection * view * vertexPosition_modelspace;
}
```

## Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

//=============================================
//---[Output Struct]---------------------------
//=============================================

out vec3 colour;

//=============================================
//---[Fragment Shader]-------------------------
//=============================================

void main()
{
    colour = vec3(1, 0, 0);
}
```

I am trying to compile them and I get the following error

*error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting "::" at token "undefined"*

I believe this may have something to do with the way I am reading the files.  Here is an example for the vertex shader file

```
std::string VertexShaderCode = FindFileOrThrow(vertex_file_path);
std::ifstream vShaderFile(VertexShaderCode.c_str());
std::stringstream vShaderData;
vShaderData << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
vShaderFile.close();
```

The file is then compiled using

```
char const *VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);
```

How can I efficiently read in the files and avoid these errors?

EDIT:

Correct compile:

```
const std::string &shaderText = vShaderData.str();
GLint textLength = (GLint)shaderText.size();
const GLchar *pText = static_cast<const GLchar *>(shaderText.c_str());
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &pText, &textLength);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);
```

Comment: Although the compiler error might mean something different, one obvious error is multiplying a `mat4` with a `vec3`, which shouldn't work (unless the newer GLSL versions have radically changed their type conversion rules).

Comment: I've since changed that to `mat4 viewProj = projection * view;`
 `gl_Position = viewProj * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);` I presume I have the multiplication the correct way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VertexShaderCode` is your *filename*, not the shader string. That's still in `vShaderData`. You need to copy the string out of `vShaderData`, and feed it into `glShaderSource`.

Comment: I've added an edit with what I think is correct.  It works but I would like any help you can give if it doesn't appear efficient.